# Order list of records in Model method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a model called "Survey", and inside of it i have a method called "steps".

```
public function steps()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StepSurvey::class);
}
```

Basically i have a relation between the survey table and other called step_surveys. In my method i need beside getting all steps order by desc using a column called "position", how can i accomplishe to change my method on the model?

Table:

```
step_surveys:
- id;
- survey_id;
- step_name
- position;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found answer:

```
public function steps(){

        $order =  $this->hasMany(StepSurvey::class);
        return $order->orderBy('position','DESC');
    }
```

Comment: You don't have to store your model in a variable. you can chain orderBy method just like this: return $this->hasMany(StepSurvey::class)->orderBy('position','DESC');